# What is the datatype for a password in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, types

I [read](http://search.cpan.org/~jsiracusa/Rose-DB-Object-0.782/lib/Rose/DB/Object/MakeMethods/Pg.pm) that there are datatypes which do encryption so passwords are secured in your database.

I use at the moment `varchar` to store passwords. I have had the idea that I should somehow apply a SHA-512 function to the password and put that data somewhere such that the plain text password is removed.

However, the datatype in Perl suggests me that there are a better way in PostgreSQL than varchar.

**What is the datatype for a password in PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Jeff has a good article titled [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/). This article discusses various ways of storing passwords in databases, and some of the common pitfalls that you may run into. In particular, it discusses the use of hashing algorithms, rainbow tables, and the use of "salt" to reduce the risk of a compromised password file.

The use of the `varchar` data type is perfectly suitable for storing a properly hashed password. For example, here is part of my actual account record from a production database:

```
=> select account_id, email, salt, passhash from account where email = 'greg@hewgill.com';
 account_id |      email       |       salt       |                 passhash                 
------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------
          1 | greg@hewgill.com | GFR9uT4N4Tzl3vnK | 2c2bf00079a6d49a8f7fb17cefb52fdb41a4b043
(1 row)
```

In this case, `passhash` is the hex representation of the SHA-1 of the salt concatenated with my password.

Comment: Should the salt be different for each account in the table Accounts?

Comment: Yes, using a different salt is required. Otherwise it's just the same as no salt at all. Jeff covers this in his article.

Comment: Great article that you are referring to. The author suggests (much) longer salts than you are using, what is your rationale for using much shorter salts?

Comment: @mvexel: the salt in my example is about 96 bits of entropy, which is more than what's in a typical password anyway. No need to go much longer than that.

Comment: This answer has been rendered obsolete by the use of GPUs for password cracking. SHA-1 isn't a suitable password hashing algorithm.

Comment: Suggestion: do not use extra column for salt. Save it as password like this: {salt}{hash}

Comment: @dieter Why not use an extra column?

Comment: @peterduffy More flexibility I think. For example, lots of password libraries will produce strings with dollar sign delimeters, like: algorithm$iterations$salt$hash. You don't want to be locked in to a single algorithm or iteration count. Encoding the extra information gives you more flexibility if you want to migrate, and having four columns separate columns for algorithm, iterations, salt, hash is a bit much. Best have the password implementation details confined to one column in my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

Install "chkpass module"

This module implements a data type chkpass that is designed for storing encrypted passwords.
You need to install the postgresql contrib package and run CREATE EXTENSION command to install .

In Ubuntu 12.04 it would go like this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Restart the postgresql server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

All available extension are in:

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/share/postgresql/extension/
```

Now you can run the CREATE EXTENSION command.

Example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION chkpass;

CREATE TABLE accounts (username varchar(100), password chkpass);
INSERT INTO accounts(username, "password") VALUES ('user1', 'pass1');
INSERT INTO accounts(username, "password") VALUES ('user2', 'pass2');

select * from accounts where password='pass2';
```

Returns

```
username | password
---------------------------
"user2"  | ":Sy8pO3795PW/k"
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this package in comparison to grep's answer where salt and hash?

Comment: chkpass uses the crypt algorithm. Hash is an algorithm that had several cases of leaked passwords in 2012. Salt is a combination, an accretion before the hash that increases security. The advantage of using chkpass is the ease of textual comparison.

Comment: Can admin see have capability of seeing real passwords? I think they should not. What is the crypt algorithm?

Comment: If this is based on an algorithm, then anybody can generate a rainbow table??

Comment: I am getting this exception

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/chkpass.control": No such file or directory

Answer (score 7):

Postgres version 9.4+ can get this done in a smarter and securer way using pgcrypto extension as explained at: http://www.meetspaceapp.com/2016/04/12/passwords-postgresql-pgcrypto.html

Comment: Can you please explain the benefits and shortcomings of the extension more clearly. Now, your answer is mostly link-only-answer.

Comment: In 2019, this leads to the most correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Mind it though, if you are thinking of postgres as a service, using it from some cloud providers, then you might not have control to install pgcrypto extension there. Beware of pitfall.

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh you can also ssh into the server and do manual operations. Its not ideal but possible.

Comment: And now the link is broken...

Comment: Since the link is down (at the time of this writing), [here's the archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20221205120659/http://www.meetspaceapp.com/2016/04/12/passwords-postgresql-pgcrypto.html).

Comment: You should post a link as an answer as they are not living forever